# how to refactor/rename macros in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, macros

if I need to rename a function or a variable on Eclipse I can just right-click on it and refactor->rename

This does not seem to work for Macro.

- Is there a way of doing it **without** using another external tool or command?

***System***:

*Eclipse Standard/SDK
Version: Kepler Release
Build id: 20130606-0932
OS: ubuntu 12.04*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Eclipse supports Macro refactoring since implementing a feature such as renaming a function is easier than implementing the same thing for, say a macro.

I also looked at the Eclipse [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-menu-refactor.htm) and the rename action does not seem to have support for Macros.